# How to real-time check the django view operating process

Tags: python, django, celery

Here is the thing, When I submit a form from template to view ,since the process of this view will cost a lot time. I don's think our user enjoy to wait.
So, I want to this: when user click the submit button,the browser will redirect to a new page or just show a sub-page in the same window that can print the real-time executing information.

Before I post this question, I did a little research, looks like the celery can do this thing, am I right? If there is same problem already be asked in stackoverflow ,PLZ give me the link.

Thank for your time!

(English is not my mother language, so I don't know if we have any term to describe this function,if we do,PLZ give me a hint )

Comment: It's certaintly possible to process the form asynconously with Celery, and that's fairly striaghtfoward to do, see this tutorial: [https://realpython.com/blog/python/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/] .However showing execution information of the asynchronous task whilst it's running might require something much more complex like websockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[django-channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) could be a good solution to send information as they execute on the server side in this way you can send information on the client side by opening a websocket.

Channel can be used to post data to the client side without having to wait for the HttpResponse.

Heroku has nice [post](https://blog.heroku.com/in_deep_with_django_channels_the_future_of_real_time_apps_in_django) explaning channels.

Hope this helps.